# Problem between unicode-math and babel option frenchb in LuaLaTeX

Tags: luatex, babel, unicode-math, french

I've got a strange problem in LuaLaTeX with both `babel`, option `frenchb`, and `unicode-math`. My TeX Distribution is TeX Live 2013 (installed with MacTeX on a OS X.8.5 system). If I run the following program:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math} % or any other math font
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\begin{document}
    \relax
\end{document}
```

I obtain this error message:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/hyph-utf8/luatex-hyphen.lua)))
! Extended mathchar used as mathchar (6300214).
<to be read again> 
=
l.244   \initiate@active@char{:}
                          %
? h
A mathchar number must be between 0 and "8000.
I changed this one to zero.
?
```

However, it works flawlessly either if I use XeLaTeX, or if I don't use the `\setmathfont` command, or if I load `babel` option `frenchb` *before* `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math} % or any other math font
\begin{document}
    \relax
\end{document}
```

Any idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: It compiles with XeLaTeX, but not with LuaLaTeX

Comment: Indeed, as I noticed… But why this difference? I don't understand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Load `babel` before `unicode-math`:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\begin{document}

a: ba : b

$a:b$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The difference lies in the fact that XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX use different methods for typesetting the colon French style, that is with equal spaces on either side.

If you add `` \the\catcode`: `` after `\begin{document}`, you'll get 13 if compiling with LuaLaTeX, but 12 if compiling with XeLaTeX. With the latter engine the shorthand features of `babel` aren't needed, while they are with LuaLaTeX.

So the *only* solution is to always load `babel` before `unicode-math`, so the activation of the shorthand characters can be acknowledged by `unicode-math`.

More precisely, LuaLaTeX uses an active colon, just like the traditional way. In XeLaTeX, the colon, semicolon, question mark and exclamation mark are placed in special `\XeTeXcharclass` arrays and rules when passing from a character in class 0 (all normal characters) or 255 (the space, although this would require many explanations) and these special classes are established. For instance, when a normal character is followed by a character in the class named `\FB@punctthick` (the colon), the code

```
\ifhmode\penalty 10000 \space\fi
```

is executed, while after a space the code inserted is

```
\ifhmode\unskip\penalty 10000 \space\fi
```

So, a possible space preceding the colon is removed (users can type a space before the colon), a penalty inhibiting a line break is inserted and a normal interword space is added.

Comment: You're right but I had already noticed that (see the last part of my question). I wanted to understand why it doesn't work if I load `frenchb` after `unicode-math`. Thanks to Herbert I see that it is (once again) a problem with the characters activated by frenchb. But how comes it works with XeLaTeX then??

Comment: @fpast Yes, I didn't notice the last part. Now you know the reason for the difference.

Comment: Great, now I understand after your answer's editing. :-)

Comment: Would using `polyglossia` instead of `babel` help?

Comment: @MartinSchröder Polyglossia doesn't work with LuaLaTeX

Comment: @egreg: AFAIK the latest version does.

Comment: @MartinSchröder I don't know how many limitations has using Polyglossia with LuaLaTeX.

Comment: @Martin Schröder: yes, `polyglossia` works now with LuaLaTeX and it does solve the problem. But `polyglossia` in its french setting is far less powerful than `frenchb` for document "frenchifying": both translate commands like `\chapter`, `\section`, etc, both insert the relevant hard spaces before punctuation when necessary, but polyglossia doesn't change the global layout of the document (e.g. list presentation, caption presentation, footnote labeling, etc.), which frenchb neatly does according to the rules of our "Imprimerie nationale française".